# iabhelper how to consume previously brought purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to solve the "Already Brought" error by querying for previously owned item then consuming them, my problem is I don't know how to get the "Purchase" object after I query for brought inventory:

I invoke the query here:

```
            List<String> st = new ArrayList<String>();
            st.add(AdRemovalSKU);
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true,st,mGotInventoryListener);
```

This is my listener implementation:

```
    mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

            if (mHelper == null) return;

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                return;
            }

            if(inventory.hasPurchase(AdRemovalSKU)) {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, context);
            }
        }
    };
```

I want to call consumeAsync, but where do I get the "purchase" variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can Check the following.

```
 mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            return;
        }
        Purchase purchased = inventory.getPurchase(AdRemovalSKU);
        if(purchased!=null){
            //Your purchase details will be in the purchased object.
            //You can also do the developer payload verification.
        }
    }
};
```

If the above code alone is not working, then you need to change following also.

```
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true,st,mGotInventoryListener);
```

To

```
   mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out, just use

```
 inventory.getPurchase(AdRemovalSKU)
```

and it will return the purchase.